# Cannot access JSON response attribute

Tags: ajax, json, jquery

I have a JSON response in JavaScript that looks like this:

```
{"opt1":"2.92","opt2":"4.24","opt3":"6.36"};
```

This is the result of applying `console.log(data)` where data is the response:

```
success: function(data){
            console.log("Ajax succeeded");
            console.log(data);
            console.log(data.opt1);
        },
```

However, I cannot access the value of opt1. The console indicates undefined. Any ideas why this could be the case? The JSON is valid, I checked it.

**EDIT**

The server in this case uses the json_encode function in PHP to convert an array to JSON. I have tried removing the semicolon at the end, this still gives me an undefined value for opt1. I also tried setting the dataType of the ajax call, that results in an error, indicating there is an unexpected character.

Comment: Does it really have a semicolon on the end? That's not valid JSON. Are you sure `console.log(data)` isn't logging the JSON string _as a string_? If you didn't explicitly tell jQuery that you're expecting JSON it tries to guess what format the response is, and I would guess that since your string is _not_ valid JSON it is not parsing it for you so you can't access properties.

Comment: Show more of the code -- are you specifying `dataType: "json"` in the AJAX call, or is the server sending `Content-type: application/json`?

Comment: @PankajGarg: 1. The answer you're pointing to has nothing whatsoever to do with the problem the OP has outlined. 2. Nagging the OP to look at your answer is *not cool* on SO. When you posted your answer, the OP was notified of that. That is sufficient. Posting a comment (much less an unnecessarily-boldfaced one) is neither appropriate nor useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like `data` may actually be a *string*, not an object.

Two things you need to do:

**First**: If that semicolon is really there, the response you're getting is not valid JSON. You'll want to fix that by removing the semicolon server-side. (But see below.)

**Second**: Then, you'll want to make sure the JSON string is *deserialized* into an object. Several ways to do that:

1. It will happen automatically if your server replies with the correct `Content-Type` header (`application/json`). This is the best way.
2. If for some reason that's not the case and you can't make it the case, add `dataType: 'json'` to your `ajax` call.
3. If for some reason you can't do *that*, you can manually parse the JSON string via [`$.parseJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/), e.g.:

   ```
   data = $.parseJSON(data);
   ```

   (Note that `parseJSON` will happily use the browser's built-in `JSON.parse` if it has one. If the browser doesn't have one, jQuery will use its own.)

---

If for some reason you can't remove the invalid `;` server-side, you can work around it:

1. Add `dataType: 'text'` to your `ajax` call
2. In `success`:

   ```
   data = $.parseJSON(data.replace(/;$/, ''));
   ```

   That will remove the semicolon if it's there, and then parse the result.

Comment: That last suggestion worked for me! Still don't quite get how this can happen though. Where did the semicolon even come from? It was just an array directly converted to a JSON object using json_encode

Comment: @danvdende: I'm glad that last option worked for you! `json_encode` definitely doesn't put a semicolon on, so I'm thinking there must be some stray output further down in the PHP file that's appending it...?

Comment: I checked the entire file, there's not other echo there... It's very odd indeed

Answer (score 0):

It's probably due to your response coming back as a string from the server (i've had the same issue)... try:

```
success: function(data){
     var json = $.parseJSON(data);
     console.log("Ajax succeeded");
     console.log(json);
     console.log(json.opt1);
},
```

Comment: You would need `$.parseJSON(data)`, not `data.toJSON()`.

Comment: Changed to parseJSON... I got toJSON from http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tojson.asp, but realised that's just a Date method.

Comment: Tried $.parseJSON(data), that gives me Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;

Comment: I'm guessing that's to do with the end semicolon not parsing then - can you remove this and try the parsing?

Comment: And, thus, my noted mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Use native call

```
json = JSON.parse(data);
```

or make the parameter of **ajax** as json like this..

```
$.ajax({
  url : blahblah,
  dataType : 'json',
  .....
});
```

In this case your response is automatically converted to json

Answer (score 0):

Try [jQuery.parseJSON(obj)](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/).

```
jQuery.parseJSON() Takes a well-formed JSON string and returns the resulting JavaScript object.
```

Use it in this way :

```
var str = '{"opt1":"2.92","opt2":"4.24","opt3":"6.36"}';
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(str);
console.log(obj.opt1);
```