# Confusing result with json conversion

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm writing a code where there is a REST call made and the result is sent back.

Using the below js code (Ajax/jQuery), I'm pulling the data.

```
success : function(msg) {
            dataObj = msg;
            var jsonResp = JSON.stringify(dataObj);

            alert(dataObj.answer + "\t" + dataObj);
            console.log(dataObj.answer + "\t"+ dataObj);
            document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = dataObj;
        }
```

The console output that I get is

```
undefined   {"answer":"Hello","score":"100"}
```

instead of

```
Hello   {"answer":"Hello","score":"100"}
```

please let me know where am I going wrong and how can I fix this.

Thanks

Comment: `msg` is a JSON string, not an object. You need to use `JSON.parse()` to convert it to an object. You can also put `dataType: 'json'` in the `$.ajax` call and then jQuery will do this automatically.

Comment: instead of JSON.stringify you should be using JSON.parse

Comment: `msg` is string or JSON Object?

Comment: @AniketSinha It's obviously a string because he's seeing it when he concatenates it into the `console.log()` call. If it were an object it would show `[object Object]`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot access JSON response attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16586512/cannot-access-json-response-attribute)

Comment: @Barmar That's what I was wondering about. Using `JSON.stringify` instead of `JSON.parse`.

Comment: @AniketSinha Why does it matter, he never uses the variable `jsonResp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dataObj = msg;
```

should be

```
dataObj = JSON.parse(msg);
```

or you can use the `dataType: 'json'` option to `$.ajax()` so that jQuery will do this automatically.